# Retrieving Autonumber Values before Commit transact

Tags: vb.net, transactions

I have an issue with retrieving Autonumber values before Commit transact. I have two tables: "Table1" which contains a column with Autonumber, and Table2.

This is my code:

```
Dim req As String = "insert into Table1 values(@val1,@val2)"
Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(req, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@val1", MyVal1))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@val2", MyVal2))
    cmd.Transaction = transaction
    nbre = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

req = "insert into Table2 values(@IdTable1, @Val)"
Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(req, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@IdTable1", ?????))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Val",MyVal))
    cmd.Transaction = transaction
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

transaction.Commit()
con.Close()
Return nbre
```

How do I find the "IdTable1" before `transaction.Commit()`?

Comment: Have a look at [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It returns the first column of the first row that you just inserted (the ID).

Comment: @ProGrammer thank you very mutch it's what i need ,your answer merit to be voted and marked :)

Comment: I would post an answer, but I have faith that Joel's answer will be a much better solution than what I suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this in one trip to the database. This makes it easier to handle the ID value, as well as eliminating the need for the transaction:

```
'Need VS2015 for the multiline string literal. Otherwise use concatenation
Dim req As String = "
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (@val1,@val2);
    SELECT @IdTable1 = scope_identity();
    INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (@IdTable1, @Val);"

Using con As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(req, con)
    'Guessing at parameter types here... it's often better to be explicit about this
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbtype.VarChar, 50).Value = MyVal1
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value =  MyVal2
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Val", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MyVal
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdTable1", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters("@IdTable1").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Return CInt(cmd.Parameters("@IdTable1").Value)
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

For the first query you want to use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to return the Auto ID that was generated by your query.

So this line:

`nbre = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Becomes:

`nbre = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

And then you can replace the `?????` with the returned ID stored in `nbre`.

NOTE:
I know this has solved the issue but I suggest implementing Joel's solution as it does what you need in a single query

Comment: Thanks @Pro Grammer ,your are right but the Joel's soution is very optimized si i vot you up .